# Sending Emails with CKEDITOR -angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular

How can I send emails with CKEditor please or I should instead use TinyMCE?

```
<ckeditor
    [(ngModel)]="ckeditorContent"
    [config]="{height:'50px', width:'50%'}"
    (change)="onChange($event)"
    (focus)="onFocus($event)"
    (blur)="onBlur($event)"
    debounce="500"

    >

  </ckeditor>
  <br/>
```

Comment: Sending email from client side ? You can format your data using CKEditor, send it to the server which send the email.

Comment: Can you explain that much better? @mickdev

Comment: CKEditor is a text editor that use javascript to ease your edition. I can be wrong, but I think there is no way you can send an email with just an editor. To achieve what you want to do, you need a web server that will retrieve your data, connect to your email account and send the email to the recipients. You can also use a email client that are compatible with CKEditor.